# Blackberry Fledge Script To Connect USB

Tags: unit-testing, blackberry, blackberry-simulator

I want to use the fledge simulator scripting tool to run automated tests for my application. I'm looking for a way to simulate a usb connection programatically (same as [through the simulator](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/6338/Simulate_a_USB_connection_607552_11.jsp)) . Is there a command that will allow me to do so?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `/comm-cable-connected` option. You can see the complete list of options by running `fledge /?` from the command line.